# Find the ratio of EF/FC

Tags: geometry

Let E be the midpoint of side AB of square ABCD. Let the circle through B with center A and segment EC meet at F. what is the ratio of $CE/EF$?

Interestingly enough, it seems like setting a point G, where G is the midpoint of line BC, can form a line DG that intersects perpendicularly with line CE and intersects exactly at F. Should this be true, then similar triangle ratios can be used to determine the ratio CE/EF. How should I show that this is true? Or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Hint: What is the angle $CEB?$

Comment: What if I suppose that calculators cannot be used, will finding angle $CEB$ still help?

Comment: Do you need one? If you have an expression for it, see where it leads you

Comment: Let me clarify my last comment - do you need the value of the angle? Will knowing it's trigonometric ratios do?

Comment: It seems like I was able to find an elementary solution involving transformation that completely avoids those, thank you for the comment anyways

Answer (score 1):

Let the side length of the square be $2$ and its vertex $A$ be at the origin:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

The point $F$ is the intersection of the circle and the line:
$$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=4\\ y=2x-2\end{cases}\Rightarrow F\left(\frac85,\frac65\right).$$
Using the similarity of $\Delta BCE$ and $\Delta EFG$:
$$\frac{CE}{EF}=\frac{CB}{FG}=\frac{2}{\frac65}=\frac53.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $BX$ be a diameter of the circle. We have that $BE:EX=1:3$. Using power of the point theorem, $EF\cdot EC=BE\cdot EX=\frac{3}{4}AB^2$. Now, $CE=\sqrt{5}AB/2$ and $EF=\frac{3}{2\sqrt{5}}AB$. Finally, $CE:EF=5:3$